# 'broot' account on Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, security

I notice some of my Centos 7 hosts have a broot account, with uid=0

broot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

does anyone know the reason for this account? I cant find documentation on 'broot' anywhere, and want to make sure this is a legit account

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"What" is easy. That is a privileged user that makes use of the traditional UID 0 checks.

"Why" is a question that needs to be answered by your organization. Absent any documentation or anyone admitting they created it, an additional privileged user does seem suspicious.

Presumably someone wanted to give root another password. Although, another UID 0 does not help with auditing specific users, or reducing privilege. So I consider it a bit of a hack.